# 2 different model based on one attribute of a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

Suppose I want to make only one table for users in ruby on rails.but I want to make 2 more model based on the role of the user. So that I can use another many to many relation between them.

```
class Patient < User
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

```
class Physician < User
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

end
```

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the appointments association you need to manually specify the foreign key column:

```
class Physician < User
  has_many :appointments, foreign_key: :physician_id 
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end
```

```
class Patient < User
  has_many :appointments, foreign_key: :patient_id 
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Also make sure you have added a `type` column to users to get [single table inheritance](https://medium.com/@ghl234/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-6-emulating-oop-principles-in-relational-databases-be60c84e0126) working.